# SQL Server: Login password changed IMMEDIATELY upon creation

Tags: sql-server

When using MS SQL Server, I keep trying to create more logins for the server with their own passwords however as soon as the login has been created, I go back to look at the login settings and see that the password has been reset to some mysterious 15 character password.

As you can imagine, this basically makes the login unusable. I've seen other cases similar to this specifically for the "sa" login however nothing on the creation of custom logins.

I've tried unchecking the "User must change password at next login", "Enforce password expiration", and "Enforce password policy" checkboxes but this has no effect. The one thing that does work is using no password at all, but obviously this is a huge security risk.

Comment: Those 15 character stars you see are just a placeholder. You could have 100 characters and you'd still see 15 stars. What makes you think the password has changed? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The login just won't work.

Comment: Have a third try at explaining your problem: What are you doing and what happens? _exactly what error do you get_?

Comment: I can create a new login, then attempt to use said login to connect to the server, at which point I get the error "Login failed for user [username]. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456).

Comment: When you created the login, did you give it access to a database also? If that's all you get in your message, I suggest you go to the SQL Server log and see if there is any more information in there (it might give you more useful information)

Comment: After creating a SQL login, you also have to create a user in each database you want that login to be able to connect to (use `CREATE USER` statement)

Comment: Check the errorlog for the reason of 18456. It can be, for example, that your server is configured to windowth authentication only. In any case the reaseon is written next to the error 18456

Answer (score 1):

MS SQL Server never store your password for security reason. MS SQL Server store only the HASH of your password.

Therefore settings form can't shown the password. Instead it shows 
`some mysterious 15 character`.